# how to view data in template when call a serve side method in meteorJs

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have used a server side method in Meteor where i am getting data from collection. I am calling server side method from client side.

Server's method returns data successfully and when I `console.log(success)`
 I got data in my callback function. But the problem is that I am not able to print this data in template. I don't know what is going wrong. Please let me know if anyone have idea about it.

Below I am showing my code.

/project/server/new.js

```
Meteor.methods({
    getResponseFromServer:function(latlong){

        lng = parseFloat(latlong.lng);

        lat = parseFloat(latlong.lat);

        var getObject = Centers.find({ coordinates: { $near: { $geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [lat,lng] }, $maxDistance: 10000 } } }).fetch();

        console.log(getObject);

        return getObject;


        }
});
```

/project/lib/router.js

```
Router.route('/search/:name', {
    name : 'searchlistDemo',
    data : function() {

        this.searchedString = Router.current().params.name;
        searchedParams = this.searchedString;
        searchedParams = searchedParams.split('-');
        var lat = searchedParams.pop();
        var lng = searchedParams.pop(1);

        lng = Number(lng).toFixed(6);
        console.log(lng);
        lat = Number(lat).toFixed(6);
        var latlong = {'lat':lat,'lng':lng};

            Meteor.call("getResponseFromServer",latlong,function(error,success){
                var searchValue =  {searchValue :success}
                console.log('we are');
                console.log(searchValue);

                return searchValue;
                //  console.log(error);
            });
    }
}

);
```

project/client/templates/search_list.html

```
<template name="searchlistDemo">


    <ul>
  {{#each searchValue}}
    <li>

      <div>{{name}}</div>
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>


</template>
```

I am using same way for client side methods, and all are working fine. But i don't know why it is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

i just used this code and now able to print data in template.i just changed few things in router.js

```
Meteor.call("getResponseFromServer",latlong,function(error,success){
                var searchValue =  {searchValue :success};
                Session.set('getServerSideResponse',searchValue);
            });

            return Session.get('getServerSideResponse');
```